# Update query on SQL Server with link server with oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, linked-server

I want to update column in SQL Server 2008 from link server (oracle) table.
I have table columns are `opr_code`, `m_code` etc.
In SQL Server table which has value in opr_code.

I want to update `m_code` value in SQL Server from link server (oracle) where common value is `opr_code` which is `conf_code` in oracle. I tried with following query

```
update test_S set m_code=A.M_CODE from
      (Select * FROM OPENQUERY(linkserver,'Select * From abcd.NAME_desk)) A
      inner join test_S B on b.opr_code=a.conf_code
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE t
SET m_code = l.m_code
FROM test_s t
JOIN OPENQUERY(linkserver,'SELECT conf_code, m_code FROM abcd.name_desk') l
ON t.opr_code = l.conf_code
```